# How to get tox to test "named" test environments with different python versions?

Tags: python, testing, tox

e.g. Let's say I have following in tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35, testenv2

[testenv]  
 # settings related to "default" testenv - includes deps, commands

[testenv:testenv2]  
 # settings related to testenv2 - includes deps, commands
```

Now when I run tox command, it invokes `testenv` commands with python 2.7 and 3.5 interpreter but `testenv2` commands only with base python installed on the machine (in my case 2.7). How to get tox to also test a "named" (non-default) test environment like `testenv2` to be tested with multiple python versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the "named" test environment to be tested with multiple python versions by making multiple "named" test environments, one each for the different python versions I wanted it to be tested with and using the `basepython` option to specify the python version for the test environment to be tested with. Below is the example that works:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35, testenv2_py27, testenv2_py35

[testenv]  
 # settings related to "default" testenv - includes deps, commands

[testenv:testenv2_py27]
basepython = python2.7 
 # settings related to testenv2 - includes deps, commands

[testenv:testenv2_py35]
basepython = python3.5  
 # settings related to testenv2 - includes deps, commands
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer describes two viable ways. For completeness: you can also generate environments and use conditional settings - e.g.:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = py{27,35}-{test,lint}
[testenv]
skip_install = True
deps =
    test: pytest
    test: pytest-xprocess
    lint: flake8
    lint: black
commands =
    test: pytest -v
    lint: flake8
    lint: black .
```

would generate (`tox -a`):

```
py27-test
py27-lint
py35-test
py35-lint
```

You can use any factor (e.g. py27 or test) to conditionally add commands, deps, etc.

See also the [docs](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#generating-environments-conditional-settings).

BTW: to see which settings each testenv exactly has you can run `tox --showconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone still needs this, I figured out an even more concise solution. It combines all the good suggestions from the other answers:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{27,35}, testenv2-py{27,35}

[testenv]  
 # settings related to "default" testenv - includes deps, commands

[testenv:testenv2-py{27,35}]
 # settings related to testenv2 - includes deps, commands
```

Answer (score 0):

List all environments explicitly:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, py35, py27-testenv2, py35-testenv2
```

If that's not enough refactor `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv]  
 # settings related to "default" testenv - includes deps, commands

[testenv2]  
 # settings related to testenv2 - includes deps, commands

[testenv:py27-testenv2]  
deps = {[testenv2]deps}
commands = {[testenv2]commands}

[testenv:py35-testenv2]  
deps = {[testenv2]deps}
commands = {[testenv2]commands}
```

Comment: The first way doesn't work. I didn't try the second way but found another way similar to yours. Will post an answer soon